# How to get a return value using Rg.Plugins.Popup in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, popup

I am using Rg.Plugins.Popup library to create a Popup alert. I don't know how to get a return value (boolean value). Can someone please help with this?

```
<pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <animations:ScaleAnimation 
                               HasBackgroundAnimation="True"
                               PositionIn="Top"
                               PositionOut="Center"
                                />
</pages:PopupPage.Animation>
<StackLayout Margin="12"
             Padding="24"
             WidthRequest="307"
             HeightRequest="264"
             HorizontalOptions="Center"
             VerticalOptions="Center">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Button BackgroundColor="#61BC52"
            Margin="0,0,18,0"
            FontSize="18"
            Text="Cancel"
            CornerRadius="20"
            WidthRequest="108"
            HeightRequest="41"
            TextColor="White" />
        <Button BackgroundColor="#61BC52"
            Text="Restart"
            FontFamily="PatrickFont"
            CornerRadius="20"
            WidthRequest="108"
            HeightRequest="41"
            TextColor="White" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

And this is how it's called from the ViewModel of my page.

```
private void RefreshIconCommandExecute(object obj)
{
    PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new RestartPopup());
}
```

Essentially, I want to be able to get the response as like the following but with the Rg Popup instead:

```
var response = App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Title", "Message", "Accept", "Cancel");
```

Comment: there are events fired for all Navigation operations - https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Navigation

Comment: you can use Messegingcenter

Comment: @sisi did you found solution to this? i am also doing same thing